How can I reliably order columns in zeppelin notebook?
I have a zeppelin notebook reading data from AWS Athena. The table looks something like this
+-----------------+-----------------+
| location        | no rain count   |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| A               | 9300            |
| B               | 977             |
| C               | 95289           |
+-----------------+-----------------+

The issue is when I use Zeppelins column ordering arrow button the no rain count is ordered alpabumericly so the column in descending order would be:
+-----------------+-----------------+
| location        | no rain count   |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| A               | 9300            |
| C               | 95289           |
| B               | 977             |
+-----------------+-----------------+

when instead it should be:
+-----------------+-----------------+
| location        | no rain count   |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| B               | 977             |
| A               | 9300            |
| C               | 95289           |
+-----------------+-----------------+

Has anyone else had this issue?
I have tried setting the column data type to Integer (it defaults the column to string) but after I try to order it using the arrow it changes back to String again. I also CAST the column to INT and the behaviour doesnt change.
Running the query directly in Athena and using the ordering arrows there works as expected so I am leaning towards this being some Zeppelin configuration issue...

If you do select typeof("no rain count") from ...  what would be the result?

Hello, I have also cast the column to INT and still same behaviour. Also worth noting that I can use the same query directly in Athena and the ordering arrows there work correctly so I am confident the issue is not with the data. Sorry, I should have mentioned that on the question.
